# Htmlagilitypack nodeception( selecting node inside another node)

Tags: c#, xaml, parsing, html-agility-pack

I have a problem. I want to get the content of the labels nodes but it didn't return me anything, because as I know, it can only be returned if it has a class or an id attribute:

```
<div class="section">
    <ul>
        <!-- vainqueur -->
        <li><label>Vainqueur</label>
            <img src="/img/maillots/jaune.gif" /> Stephen ROCHE <img src="/img/drapeau/IRL.jpg"> (CARRERA JEANS)
        </li>
        <!-- nb etapes -->
        <li><label>Nombre d'&eacute;tapes</label>25</li>
        <!-- 1 -->
        <li><label>Distance</label>4231 km</li>
        <!-- 1 -->
        <li><label>Vitesse moyenne</label>36.645 km/h</li>
        <!-- 1 -->
        <li><label>Prime au vainqueur</label>300 000&nbsp;F</li>
        <!-- 1 -->
        <li><label>Total des primes</label>6 284 700&nbsp;F</li>
    </ul><!-- fin ul resume -->
</div><!-- fin div section -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the labels and loop them. try with this code

```
string htmlText = @"<div class=""section"">
                    <ul>
                        <!-- vainqueur -->
                        <li><label>Vainqueur</label>
                            <img src=""/img/maillots/jaune.gif"" /> Stephen ROCHE <img src=""/img/drapeau/IRL.jpg""> (CARRERA JEANS)
                        </li>
                        <!-- nb etapes -->
                        <li><label>Nombre d'&eacute;tapes</label>25</li>
                        <!-- 1 -->
                        <li><label>Distance</label>4231 km</li>
                        <!-- 1 -->
                        <li><label>Vitesse moyenne</label>36.645 km/h</li>
                        <!-- 1 -->
                        <li><label>Prime au vainqueur</label>300 000&nbsp;F</li>
                        <!-- 1 -->
                        <li><label>Total des primes</label>6 284 700&nbsp;F</li>
                    </ul><!-- fin ul resume -->
                </div><!-- fin div section -->";
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(new StringReader(htmlText));

       foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//label"))
       {
           Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
       }
```